# How to set tabindex for ui-timepicker (angular bootsrap)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there is a possibility to modify the tabindex of the arrows and set it to -1 (tabindex = "- 1")

Here is an example :  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.14.1/#/timepicker

Answer (score 0):

I added `tabindex`attr and works quite well.

```
  <uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" tabindex="-1" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
```

Example [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rzm42N9jD75HVo4LUXkr?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @agriboz, but I want to add tabindex="-1" just for the arrows !

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution but I do not know is that there is another better than this (to modify the tabindex of the arrows) !!

```
this.$timeout(function () { // You might need this timeout to be sure its run after DOM render.
        angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( 'td.uib-increment.hours > .btn.btn-link' )).attr('tabindex','-1')
        angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( 'td.uib-increment.minutes > .btn.btn-link' )).attr('tabindex','-1')
        angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( 'td.uib-decrement.hours > .btn.btn-link' )).attr('tabindex','-1')
        angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( 'td.uib-decrement.minutes > .btn.btn-link' )).attr('tabindex','-1')
    }, 0, false)
```